# Are questions about journals and citation management on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1768/81) on the [computational science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. I thought the question (about finding DOIs from a list of formatted citations) would be a good fit for the site, but one of the other commentators said it was off-topic according to the [FAQ](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq). My interpretation of the FAQ is that it would be on-topic.

Should this question be on topic?

Comment: I don't think it is, but I'd love to see it answered somewhere. Perhaps open-source projects such as paperpile or zotero have tackled this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions on citation management are generally on topic, as that is an important part of an academics' job. As the FAQ cites, questions related to a specific journal are normally off-topic, but questions about general procedures and issues related to them would be on-topic.

I guess the best thing to do would be to provide an example of the kind of question you'd like to post. (The question on the scicomp board would not be appropriate here, but other questions in that area might be.)

Comment: Is [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36/546) on-topic?

Comment: That question is borderline. It's not really a good fit for a Q&A-type board, inasmuch as it asks for a list and can lead to lots of arguments back and forth. That said, the question does have value as an archival source, so I'd be reluctant to use mod powers to delete it. I would leave it to the community to take such actions, if they felt it appropriate.